# What's the correct way to name a method that returns a boolean?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

I was reading about naming conventions and I like the way Java is so organized about it.
But one thing caught my attention.

In Java, and other programming languages as well, a method that returns a boolean is usually named in two ways:

> isSomething()

or

> hasSomething()

But we have a classic method built-in which is

> equals()

Which doesn't follow the standard.
Shouldn't it be

> isEqualsTo()

?

Comment: `isEqualsTo()` - looks as to difficult, and longer to type

Comment: The answer is `equalp()`.  See http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_equalp.htm

Comment: Java doesn't take that naming convention all _that_ far.  For example, the `Collection` API doesn't go for naming conventions much at all, with the possible single exception of `isEmpty`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is primarily a opinion based question. But as such there is as such no best way. Neither any standard for it. Take the name whichever you find more readable and understandable

Answer (score 0):

yep you are right..

i would call it

```
isEquals()
```

another well-known way is to do the C way

```
bEquals()
```

the 'b' (for boolean) is the return type..

```
iAddition
```

will return 'i' (for integer) and so on..

it´s up to you..